# Call Javascript function across pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hyperlink in the index file, which calls an HTML file. This HTML file has a button and some instructions. Once clicked the button, it is supposed to call a function from another HTML page and display a summary of some calculations.

I have used `<link>`, `<script src=>` etc. but I always get the error that the function assigned to the "button click" is not available. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

---

Did a bit more research on how to post here and following is the script, better presented.

**file 1 - index.html**

`<html>`, `<head>,``, Increment count when button is clicked`

`The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">`0`</span>` times.`</p>` `</body>` `</html>`

**file 2 - test.js**

`<script LANGUAGE="javascript">` var count = 0; var button = document.getElementById("countButton"); var display = document.getElementById("displayCount"); button.onclick = function(){ count++; display.innerHTML = count; } `</script>`

Cheers

Comment: It's impossible to tell what could be wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: Okay so you wrote inline JavaScript that you want to use in another inlined script? It's the opposite way to do it, actually. Write your code once and for all in a `.js` file and use `script` tags to call the file where needed instead.

Comment: You can use the "edit" button to add more data to your question, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your function in another file (js file) and include it in your pages `head` tags.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="myfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ........
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the source file.

Comment: You should post the code to help you. Double check the syntax of the function name. It should be `onclick="function_name"` (without parentheses) and it's name is case sensitive. And make sure no syntax errors in the js file

Comment: have added the code above. Yes onclick=function_name. Infact it works great when they are in a single page.

Comment: You should add the <script> tag in each page .

Comment: Yes, have done that...js file has <script></script>, html file has <script src=test.js></script>

Comment: Can you share th code ?. And you should put quotation marks in src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that script/functionality on that page also, where button is present.